# I cant present a viewcontroller from app delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c

**Code:**

**Appdelegate.h**

```
- (void)goNativeStoryboardToTwilio;
```

**Appdelegate.m**

```
-(void)goNativeStoryboardToTwilio {

  DummyViewController *vc = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"NativeStoryboard" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"dummy"];
  [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:vc animated:true completion:nil];
}
```

**RoomInputToolbarView.m:**

```
- (IBAction)twilioCall:(UIButton *)sender {
  AppDelegate *appdel=(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
  [appdel goNativeStoryboardToTwilio];
}
```

**RoomInputToolbarView.xib:**

[That call image is the twilioCall action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bK3U7.png)

**Result:**

```
Warning: Attempt to present <DummyViewController: 0x1565f9910> on <UIViewController: 0x157831460> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

Im not redirected to that page. Can someone help me with this issue please.

### Update

**Appdelegate.m**

```
-(void)goNativeStoryboardToTwilio {
  double delayInSeconds = 10.0;
  dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
  dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    DummyViewController *vc = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"NativeStoryboard" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"dummy"];
    [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:vc animated:true completion:nil];
  });
}
```

Even now i get the same result. But all the logs that were printed in that view controller is getting printed, only the screen is not changing. Can anyone suggest me a solution?

Comment: why are you presenting controller in app delegate??

Comment: I think you are missing this line. [window makeKeyAndVisible]; please add this in above method as well and then check.

Comment: Show where are you calling the method `goNativeStoryboardToTwilio`

Comment: Hi @RahulGUsai, I'm trying to call a view controller from the object file so I'm using app delegate for presenting that dummy view controller.

Comment: Hi @zero, As you have requested I have edited my above question. Kindly check that.

Comment: In your update for Appdelegate, change this line:
`[self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:vc animated:true completion:nil];` to this line and tell us what happens now: `self.window.rootViewController = vc;`

Comment: HI @aBilal17 i have added that line you gave in your comment above the dummy view controller initialisation even though I'm not getting what I'm expecting and I'm getting the same waring Attempt to present <DummyViewController: 0x1565f9910> on <UIViewController: 0x157831460> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're calling present early before even the VC is laid completely in the window , so you need to delay that or defer it inside ViewController's override methods

Comment: Can I know which view controller you are speaking about. Its about appdelegate or the dummy view controller that I have created?